# Why is no isomorphism possible from $(\Bbb Q^*,\cdot)$ to $(\Bbb R^*,\cdot)?$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Why is no isomorphism possible from $(\Bbb Q^*,\cdot)$ to $(\Bbb R^*,\cdot)?$

Is it happening for different cardinalities of the groups?Is there any reason related to homomorphism?Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean the group of rationals under multiplication and the group of reals under multiplication?

Comment: If yes, then, you are right that the key point is that these groups have different cardinalities, so no *bijection* is even possible. (An isomorphism has to be a bijection.)

Comment: You must consider non zero rationals or reals.Isn't it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I think by $(Q^*,.)$ you mean the group of nonzero rationals under multiplication, and by $(R^*,.)$ you mean the group of nonzero reals under multiplication. If so, then you are right that because they have different cardinalities there can be no isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Each isomorphism is a bijection, so must preserve cardinality; those two groups have different cardinality; hence there does not exist an isomorphism between them.